# WARNING **: Couldn't find pixmap file

Tags: windows, gtk, windows-vista, glade

Working with Windows Vista. I wrote the rough interface out with Glade so I am working from that source. GTK 2.0. When I compile & run I get the above error. Is there a way to absolute path images? If not how in the world do I find it? I tried add_pixmap_directory using the absolute path with no luck. Ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to load an image, or an icon?

Comment: image1 = create_pixmap (dialog1, "business_256.png"); which will be an decoration in an area I have open with nothing. Mitch I don't disagree but realistically the world runs on Windows. I am tip toeing into the waters to see what it's like. So far since I have been able to take GTK with me not to bad.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was Msys. I swapped & started using MinGW. MSys was not writing out the output file so I just kept getting the same error as the file was not being overwritten. All is good now.